# Effective weight (at both design time, runtime, etc.) of extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I was wondering what is the effective weight of extension methods, if used very wildly.

If, for example, I decide to create a lot of string/int/datetime extension methods for many of the common day-to-day tasks, to obtain a kind of fluent interface as a result, it may be that the overall weight would pump up excessively? And if yes, would it be at design time (e.g. IntelliSense db growing too much) or runtime or both? Or none of them?

To avoid a massive amount of IntelliSense-suggested methods everywhere, I was thinking about putting them inside a separate namespace like "MyCompany.PathExtensions" or "MyCompany.DateTimeExtensions" or even all of them in a fancy "MyCompany.FluentEverywhere" or similiar...

An example of what I'm talking about:

```
DateTime d;
d = 23.Minutes().FromNow();
d = "14".ToIntOr(0).IsBetween(10,20).IfFalseThrow(new Exception("foo"));

String finalPath;
// This will give you "c:\foo\bar\"
finalPath = "c:\\".AppendPath("foo").AppendPath("bar").EnsureTrailingBackslash();

String finalUrl;
// This will give you "ftp://mycompany.com/foo/bar"
finalPath = "mycompany".EnsureDomainExtensionOr("com").AppendPath("foo/bar").EnsureTrailingSlashNotThere().EnsureProtocolOr("ftp");
```

And so on... Oh, and do not go berserk on things like `.IfFalseThrow(...)`, they were just examples.

What do you think? Apart from the usage, that is likable, or not depending on tastes, there may be problems relating overall weight?

Comment: Woooh woh, didn't want to start a flame, sorry Aaronaught! The ones i've posted were just *examples*. I've even wrote that clearly after the code block, with a smiley too. I could've just said `banana.Eat().Burp()`, they were not intended to write a new bible.

Comment: Alright, maybe the comments were a bit much... still, please don't implement extension methods like these, they're a form of obfuscation.  The important thing is: You don't need to use extension methods at all for this, if you're trying to design a fluent syntax then it is usually better to start from your own base class, not write extension methods to the most common framework classes.

Comment: @Aaronaught - Like pretty much the entire Linq library does? :)

Comment: @aaronaught: don't worry about the comments, i know these kind of arguments tend to put us coder in crazy mode. It happens to me too :D 

Anyway I kind of agree with your view, except that you may find usefull composability (not *real* OO composability), in having for example 3 or 4 libraries with different sets of extension methods all for strings, for example. One that deal with hypenization and similiar stuff, another one for soundex-related stuff, and so on. And i was thinking about a clean way to use them all glued togheter and not having to use 4 different builder-classes.

Comment: @Nick Craver: No, not really, Linq mostly extends `IEnumerable<T>`, not `int` and `string`.  The methods are all sequence transformations, and they're implemented as extension methods for a reason (because an interface can't contain method bodies).  Attaching an entire custom grammar to primitive types is very, very far afield from what Linq does.

Comment: @aaronaught: anyway most in general i would've liked to discuss about possible hidden stuff both at code-time/run-time just for the sake of knowing that. Without any particular thing in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellisense may grind extra fetching the methods, but at runtime you're calling a bunch of statically defined methods, they're very lightweight.

Now some of the Linq extension methods are heavy but that's because they're **doing work**, not just because they're extension methods.

Like you said, it's all a matter of preference with the look/chainability, etc...but for performance, there's **nothing added by using an extension method for something**.

Comment: Thanks Nick, in fact apart from code time i did suspect there were not that much at runtime, but would like to be sure about that, discussing a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

> what is the effective weight of extension methods

Exactly the same as effect of using **static methods**.
Extensions methods are no more, no less than just static methods wrapped by C# syntax sugar to look like normal methods.

Comment: I know that they are static methods, it's kinda clear when you write them ;) ... but they are not *just* that. In fact the "syntactic sugar" has a cost, at least at design/coding time: intellisense database growing (maybe?) too much, and so on... i tought about discussing about that subject

Comment: It only has the cost during compilation, debugging. As every method that you declare. If you want to avoid "overhead", then don't declare anything :). Seriously, it is so misarable that I would even never though to ask about it. Especially when it does not effect performance in production.